# Cannot return model with belongsTo in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return a school model with its associated region, but it throws an exception: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$region`

What I have now:

**School model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class School extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'street', 'house_number', 'city', 'phone', 'email', 'withdrawed', 'region_id'
    ];

    public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
    }
}
```

**Region model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Region extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function schools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\School');
    }
}
```

And in my controller I am trying this:

```
$schools = School::where('withdrawed', '<', 50000)->orderBy('withdrawed', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
$schools->region;
return $schools;
```

Why it's not working this way? I've got another relation, but M:N and there it works fine by this approach... Could anyone tell me, where's the problem?

Comment: Remove the get call. That returns a collection and thus u don't have access to a region method. Next, u can't call the region method as you are currently doing, you would need to do it on each instance of the returned model, so use a loop. Furthermore in the code you are showing you are not doing anything w the region anyway.. Maybe explain more about what you are trying to achieve like where you are going to use the schools returned, then I can give u an answer in code :-p

Comment: I want to return 5 schools with it's regions (each school belongs to one) ... I am using laravel as an api :)

Comment: I got it :-D `return School::where('withdrawed', '<', 50000)->orderBy('withdrawed', 'desc')->take(5)->with('region')->get();`

Comment: nice ;) good luck